# How to handle complication after just getting hired

Tags: communication, new-job, human-resources

I just got hired to fill an accounts receivable position that I’ve been excited for.
I just got notified that my husband has chosen to change careers after his Semi-truck’s engine ‘blew up’.
This will make it nearly impossible to work weekends, which is one of the requirements. I’ve looked into weekend childcare and can’t find anything.
How do I deal with this unexpected complication without ruining my relationship with the company?

Comment: Your husband "notified" you that he was doing something which screwed your professional career? I hope there was an actual discussion about this.

Comment: While Philip has assumed you wish to resign over this, what is your end goal here?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Well, I am assuming that there isn't flexibility around this and at that point the best terms to leave on are resigning rather than being fired.

Comment: How is "working weekends" a requirement for an accounting job? That must be some damn urgent accounting they are doing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - In ordinary circumstances, I'd agree with you, but with the supply-chain issues that have plagued the US over the last year, getting parts to keep semi trucks on the road has been neigh impossible, and a large number of tractors are sidelined and not likely to come back online soon.  A destroyed engine block is practically a death sentence to a tractor, today, and I don't think the husband had a choice.

Comment: @nvoigt - Not if it's in the retail sector.  Getting a shop to pay their suppliers in order to receive more inventory could very well be a "Saturday afternoon emergency."

Comment: @WesleyLong A career change may be necessary. Forcing a career change on your partner _without discussion_, absolutely not.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - I would contend that the piston rods on the tractor were what forced the career change.  This is a catastrophic event to owner/operators.

Comment: So your husband just lost his job, and he hasn't started a new one yet? Is that correct? Why should you be the one to quit your job? Can't he find a job that works weekdays instead? Why should you be the one to quit your job for a job that he hasn't even started yet? That's the part that I don't understand. Also realistically, how many hours will you be expected to work on weekends? Is that just a few hours? Is that even guaranteed? Could you go work on Saturdays on very early mornings? Also if you quit now, know that you won't get any unemployment.

Answer (score 8):

Other than finding a new company to work for that doesn't require weekends or speaking to your husband and working things out as a couple, the only thing you can to is to talk to your boss.

Let them know that your situation has changed and that your availability on weekends has been diminished.  You should offer to make up any missed weekend days on week days.  Hopefully your boss/company is flexible and can help to accommodate for your situation.

Most likely, they will not and you will have to start looking for a new company to work here.  This of course assumes that you cannot resolve the situation first with your husband.

Comment: In addition to this answer, as a last resort, you could offer to work remotely if that is possible. Obviously your employer would have to be satisfied that you are able to mind your children in addition to working. (They may be of a suitable age where this is possible).

Answer (score 1):

You walk into your boss's (virtual) office and say something like

> Unfortunately, due to a change in my personal circumstances I am no longer able to work weekends. I appreciate that is a requirement for the position so I am submitting my resignation.
>
> Thank you for hiring me for this position, and I apologise for this change. I'm happy to work what I can until you can fill the position with someone else.

They probably won't be ecstatic, but a reasonable employer will understand that stuff happens and sometime's it's outside your control.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible scenarios:

**1. Asking for a few weeks to find a solution:**

Can you tell the boss about your current situation, and ask him to give you a few weeks to find a good solution and then, after that, you can return to working on the weekend ? During this time, you ask him to allow you not to work on the weekends.

Or maybe, during this time, you can **work a few hours extra onsite in the evening** to make up for the time that you will not work on these weekends ? You can try to ask the boss.

Also, is it possible for the boss to ask some of your coworkers to **temporarily** take over your job on these weekends while you are looking for a long-termed solution ?

**2. Working remotely on the weekend for a few weeks:**

If your boss allows you to working remotely on the weekend for a few weeks, that will be great. Then, after that, you will go back to working onsite on the weekend. You can ask the boss to find out his preference.